# FLAC seeking with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I found out that seeking FLAC files using av_seek_frame() doesn't really work with ffmpeg. Decoding FLAC to raw PCM works fine but as soon as I have called av_seek_frame(), the next call to av_read_frame() will return -1, i.e. end of file.

I peeked into the source code and found out the following cause: seeking in FLAC is implemented in the av_seek_frame_generic() function inside libavformat/utils.c. What this function basically does is calling av_read_frame() in a loop and checking the packet timestamps against the desired seek position.

The reason why it doesn't work with FLAC is that the FLAC packets don't contain any timestamps because the FLAC decoder uses some generic reader that always pulls packets of a hard-coded size of 1024 bytes from the stream.

I'm not using the latest version of ffpmeg but an older one but as FLAC playback works just fine I don't want to switch to the latest one because this would mean significant work for me because I've adapted this older version of ffmpeg to my specific needs. That's why I'd like to ask the question if anybody has an idea how I could fix FLAC seeking in this older version of ffmpeg (to be specific, it is version 0.6 from 2010).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it wasn't supported at all in 0.6 because there was no FLAC parser in that version. I've now taken the FLAC parser from 0.8 and merged it with version 0.6. So it's working fine now.